# Programmatically create a service SAS token for Storage Account in Azure

Tags: azure

From the Azure portal I would like to programmatically and periodically create a service SAS token. Once a token has been created it should expire in one week and a new token also valid for one week will be created and so on. I was reading this article https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/storage/blobs/sas-service-create?tabs=dotnet but I am not very sure about where that code should run, in a Azure VM?  I can't give internet access to the VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code from the article can be run from any compute service.

If that is the sole purpose of the compute resource, I would pick **Logic Apps** to have everything managed for you; it may have a connector to do it or you can embed some **JavaScript**.

Should that not be sufficient, I would use an **Azure Function**.

You can also use a **VM** if that is more suitable and restrict/block its internet access.

If you need to restrict internet access, you must be sure your blob storage is reachable, your options are:

1. Open whichever **firewall**/**NSG** to that storage account
2. Using service endpoints, service endpoint policies
3. Project a **Private Link endpoint** into the **VNET** from the storage

Comment: @FabStack short answer for SA/VM: yes; long answer: the SA will need to use Private Link to be in the same VNET as it has public access by default, then you can restrict the VNET in/out bound as you pointed out. For the SDK: You can even use the REST API and not install the packages at all, or you can pre-package your app and install it in the VM so that the VM never needs access to the packages feed.

Comment: thanks Stefano, Logic Apps just allows to create a SAS URI, but I need the SAS token. Could you give me some documentation to have a VM with prepackage?

Comment: @FabStack Logic Apps can invoke REST APIs, so it can get a SAS token even if it does not have a specific connector for it (but, without an integrated environment, the SA needs to be on the public internet). If your VM is on a private network together with your storage account, you could even put your package on the storage and let the VM download it from there. You can do it manually or, better, run a DSC VM extension to auto-download and install on VM creation.